# Django Slow on Production, fast in test

Tags: django, performance

Our web sites hosted with Django are extremely slow on the production server: Database access seems slow (Mysql), downloading a file is slow (I tried X-Sendfile, but without impact).

Profiling using something based on [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/186/), the heaviest:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 11570    0.577    0.000    0.577    0.000 /var/lib/python-support/python2.6/MySQLdb/times.py:43(DateTime_or_None)
  5786    0.500    0.000    0.617    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py:244(__init__)
  5796    0.205    0.000    0.576    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py:411(render_option)
     8    0.190    0.024    1.014    0.127 /var/lib/python-support/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py:282(_fetch_row)

21.6%   0.577 /var/lib/python-support/python2.6/MySQLdb/times.py
19.4%   0.520 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py
 9.5%   0.253 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py
 7.4%   0.199 /var/lib/python-support/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py

33.0%   0.882 /var/lib/python-support/python2.6/MySQLdb
32.6%   0.873 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db
15.4%   0.413 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/forms
10.5%   0.280 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils
```

This call above was run on a admin page.

What I could do:
 - update the mysql
 - update the whole django framework (still running on 1.1)

But I think, there must be something else why this is so slow. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to use a monitoring app like newrelic?

Comment: are you try to use django cache_backend and cache_timeout

Comment: @newrelic: no, I haven't.

Comment: @abda2005: there seems to be a combination of things: caching does have a problem + possible configuration problems on apache and mysql

Answer (score 0):

It should be slow only for the first time on production server but for the following access to the pages the behavior should be different if django memcached for example.

```
 install django-memcached on production server

 settings.py:

 CACHE_BACKEND ="memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/" # change the IP to the server IP
 CACHE_TIMEOUT =60*60     #to keep items in the cache it's up to you

 # if you wish to cache some data which are permanently in high demand 
 views.py :
 from django.core.cache import cache
 from project.settings import CACHE_TIMEOUT
 # example of how to use the cache in the methods
 def method(request):
    model_cache_key = request.path
c = cache.get(model_cache_key)
if not c:
    c=get_object_or_404(model,id=self.id)
    cache.set(model_cache_key,c,CACHE_TIMEOUT)
#END OF USE CACHE HERE
foo=c.modelname_set.all()
    # more code here
    return #whatever you want
```

Comment: I do something like this. But there seems to be a combination of things: caching does have a problem (now disabled) + possible configuration problems on apache and mysql. I think, I come back later to this after doing some more research. Even when disabled I would expect faster loads of some access. Sometimes it requires dozens of seconds to load. Can caching alone be the problem?

Comment: it's cannot be a problem, it help in to scale our system. let me do some research and back to you later.

Comment: i forgot to tell that you should define a property of cache for your models, something like this : @property
                           def cache_key(self):
                    return self.get_absolute_url() # if you use get_absolute_url() to return your url.   you should define it , before to be able to use them in the views (model_cache_key). let me know if you don't understand that.

Comment: Sorry, currently I have to work on something else so I can't dive into this. But thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in your profile output, that a lot of time is spent in function `DateTime_or_None` from MySQLdb.

I recently came across the same issue and it seems that the use of `DATETIME` fields in MySQL is not a good idea, especially with python because of very slow and usually unnecessary conversion to python `datetime` type.

I found some articles about it:

- [Don't Waste Time With Python, MySQL, and datetime](http://blog.client9.com/2010/02/19/dont-waste-time-with-python-mysql-and.html) - this one is quite old(Feb 2010), but still relevant
- [Why MySQL’s (SQL) DATETIME can and should be avoided](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2009/03/mysql-datetime-epoch-unix-time/) - a lot of interesting comments on the topic.

Well, I'm not sure that dropping `DATETIME` would be right solution, maybe changing from MySQLdb to some other MySQL adapter will help improve perfomance.